# ExtJS Toolbar Overflow Handler not displaying on screen resize

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have created a toolbar inside a panel header but the overflow menu doesn't appear on screen resize.
Menu when the screen is not resized
[image]
On Screen resize the buttons are not showing in overflow menu.
[image]

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                collapsible: true,
                header: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'title',
                        flex: undefined
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        width: 400,
                        overflowHandler: 'menu',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test1'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test2'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test3'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test4'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test5'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test6'
                        }],

                    }, {
                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                    }]

                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is this extjs 6 classic or modern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3htk).  I set a layout using hbox and set a flex on the two different components in the header.  also set the panel and header to resizable: true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I am able to get the menu but it is not getting rendered completely and shows on the far right of the panel,would be great if you can help i have updated the screenshot at the end

Comment: it is difficlut to see the problem with the screen shot.  do you have a fiddle or public accessable exmaple?

Comment: Identified the issue it works fine now

Comment: you can update my fiddle with you solution to help out the next guy!

Comment: No changes required in the fiddle changes were my application specific